# Use the Python C-API to determine if an object is valid?

Tags: python, c, validation

Summary: Is there some way in the Python C-API to determine if a PyObject* points to a valid Python object?

Context: I'm writing a bridge in C code between IDL (the Interactive Data Language) and Python. When a Python object gets wrapped in an IDL object, the first thing I do is increment the Python ref count using the following C code:

```
PyObject *pyObj = (PyObject *) id;
Py_INCREF(pyObj);
```

The problem: Normally, the integer "id" that gets passed into my wrapping function has been created by my bridge code, so I can trust that it is a valid Python identifier (i.e. it points to a "real" Python object). However, if the user tries to create one of these objects manually and just passes in a random integer for the Python id, then Python seg faults on the Py_INCREF and crashes the application.

I'd like to put in a sanity check, just to verify that the pointer does indeed point to a valid Python object. I cannot find anything in the Python C API that actually checks if a given pointer is indeed a valid Python object. I tried calling the built-in "id" method, as well as the garbage collector "gc.is_tracked()" but they also just crash if given a bad pointer.

Is there anything in the Python C-API that will verify that a PyObject pointer is valid?

Comment: What's the actual value of the pointer when the object is invalid?  It's probably NULL.

Comment: I can trap null values. The problem is when the user just blindly passes in an actual integer value (perhaps a stale value from earlier in the session).

Comment: By saying: `(PyObject *) id;` you're letting the user of your code pass whatever he wants in as id.  Unless you provide a more complete example all I can say is don't allow casts like this (without protecting wrapping code).  Ideally `id` would have been returned to you by the python c-api and no casting would be required (the compiler is trying to help you and you're ignoring it).

Comment: There's not much more of a "complete example". When my code wraps a Python object, I retrieve the Python id, increment the ref count, cast it to a 64-bit integer, and stash it in the IDL object. Maybe my real question should have been "should I consider PyObject pointers as *just* like C pointers in terms of danger?" In other words, you better know what you're doing with that pointer and don't let it get messed up. I was just hoping for some safe way to test a PyObject*. If there isn't any way to do that, I'll just try to protect the user from themselves as best as possible.

Comment: They're just c pointers, there's no magic.  If you go: `int x; PyObject* pyObj = (PyObject*)x; Py_INCREF(pyObj);`   it's going to blow up.

Comment: Okay, thanks Alex, that's what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is "no", there is no way using the Python C API to determine if a PyObject pointer is valid. The usual rules of using C pointers apply - be careful, and know what you're doing!

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm embedding my Python and am anal about mixing references, I track my own using C++ std::list

```
static std::list<PyObject*> PyObjObjs;     //  Python variables, numeric and string
MSEXPORT void AddToPyObjects(PyObject* V) { PyObjObjs.push_back(V); }

bool IsPyObject(PyObject* addr) //  check for validity, use <list> to track all Python objects, avoid SEGFAULT
{
    if (addr == NULL)
        {ObjErr.str = new string("NULL Python Object"); ObjErr.err = true; return false;}
    bool b = false;
    for (auto i : PyObjObjs) { if (i == addr) { b = true; break; } }
    if (b) return true;
    else
        {ObjErr.str = new string("Invalid Python object (unallocated memory or non-Python object)"); ObjErr.err = true; return false;}
}
```

NOTE:  If I keep everything I do in C++, I'm unlikely to need this kind of check function, but since my calling LabVIEW code can't distinguish between unsigned pointers, it helps me to track my own while debugging.